# How do I convert a website entirely made from frames into HTML?

Tags: html, html-frames

I am looking to convert a clients website into HTML. I'm relatively new as my skills are more directed in the front end of websites (design) so I'm quite lost. The website is [allegianceglobalinvestigations.com](http://allegianceglobalinvestigations.com) and if you scroll through it, each page has the same URL. How to I create a HTML file/template from this? I'm assuming that since there are 4 pages, I'll end up with 4 files? Do I need to use OCR for the text?

Comment: That's not a website. It's 4-slide slideshow...

Comment: I think you should start learning HTML first, and you will need CSS too. So, enjoy learning!!

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source it will show you the urls of the other frames. If you view just that url you can get the source for just that frame. You can use that source all together with some changes if you're trying to just "un-framify" the site. I think that was what you were asking.

There is very little text on there so the only OCR you will need is your eyes and a keyboard if you're trying to use real text on the site.

And yes, you will end up with 4 different files. One for each page.

Good luck with your project, the best way to learn is to dive right in!

Answer (score 0):

This is a frame-based site with a top menu in one frame selecting between four pages in the other frame. The content of each subpage is encoded as a JPEG image in a table.

**There are already files for each subpage:** `content.htm`, `sis.html`, `services.htm`, and `contact.htm`. With this low amount of text, you may as well just type the text currently in the images into the body of these files instead of using OCR. Replace everything between `<body>` and `</body>` with the text, then use HTML to mark up to the content to your liking.

**To eliminate the frames**, paste the content of the body element from the `menu.htm` file into the start of the body element of the four subpages.